# Typescript Partial of Extended Type Property [TS2322]

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble explaining my issue, so my best bet is really a minimal example. See below:

```js
type Result = {
    prop1: {
        val1: number,
        val2: string
    },
    prop2: {
        val1: number
    }
};

function somefn<T extends Result>(): Partial<T['prop1']> {
    return({val1: 1}); // <- Error: Type '{ val1: 1; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T["prop1"]>'.ts(2322)
}
```

Why isn't `{val1: 1}` detected as valid `Partial<T['prop1']>` for any T. Isn't it? Any type that extends Result should have prop1.val1: number. Or is there something to this that I am not understanding?

Edit: About the narrowing of number. How come the following does not report an error?

```
type Result = {
    prop1: {
        val1: number
    },
    prop2: {
        val1: number
    }
};

function somefn<T extends Result>(): Partial<T['prop1']> {
    return({val1: 1}); 
}
```

With val1 as the only property, it seems to be ok with it.

Comment: Not truly a minimal example, since prop2 isn't necessary at all to reproduce the problem. But val2 does seem to be required to reproduce the problem. As if the "Partial" part of it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all types that extend `Result` can have any number (like `1`) at `prop1.val1`. Take for example this `AnnoyingResult`:

```
type AnnoyingResult = {prop1: {val1: 0, val2: '0'}, prop2: {val1: 0}}
```

It extends `Result`, so

```
const x = somefn<AnnoyingResult>()
```

is a valid call, but `prop1.val1` has type `0`, so `{val1: 1}` cannot be assigned to `Partial<AnnoyingResult['prop1']>`, which is what the type error signals.

The `returnOne` function below is a simpler example of the same problem:

```
function returnOne <T extends number>(): T {
    return 1; 
    // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    // 'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
    // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFfUYATgPZgCMAXNngXQG4CGyVUAdogLYBGERANLTr4myAEzV4wIgEs2AcyFQAvoLrEyEmsIKjWHHnyXKcygNw4cAM0RsAxsBkk2UeCU4QrbADwAVKBAAHsAQbAAm8LAIKMAAfAAUAJTUAAqMRI7MfgDaAEQaFLkAurHaBEQQwIhELvFYetTkyolmUAD0bVDeALRQAKJEpETUvuDQAORYUA1Q5K3K41AykWwkaIzw8DLybIzcyNDAJFCgkFDjaRkyWb55BeTFseMAdMDw8WIAzGJiiaaWp2gAEE2KsQHJ5HAkKgMNh7tR6sxWAAGfjTZhacbI8aqQikMBaREsajI5QmHB2ZxSKCBWFuDxebwgsEQqExBJ-ay2BxOFwVKo1ADybAgfgCwVCEXYXF4RA5IzK%20H51RccygSg6-UGJGGUFGZ3GBlli2W7DWUA2Wx2ewOJ2OgPOvheGs6hplfBNkUt212%200O9oAFtBKWwpERGHI0CQrCcxo7xmoCJruIg0OMnVBKSgwlBeEtQ8BGGxMiEcwB3GTAAMWqBhGRWKx8UJoJDcB3RzNU6QR4vnI0e57-CldqAgWHKoUi7zIjlAA)

Comment: I see! So the issue is that `number` can be narrowed by an extending type. This always seems to trip me up when my conception of inheritance is always around interfaces and not the primitive types. I wish there was some sort of "extends" without primitive type narrowing.

Comment: An additional question is why does the following not report an error?:

Comment: ```type Result = {
    prop1: {
        val1: number
    },
    prop2: {
        val1: number
    }
};

function somefn<T extends Result>(): Partial<T['prop1']> {
    return({val1: 1}); 
}```

Comment: Adding additional question into the main post. Comment formatting doesn't work.

Comment: Don't know why this is accepted. My guess would be that it is hard to do type inference here with the mapped type `Partial` and a generic `T`. Maybe the same reason why the original error does not mention the different subtype of the constraint. It would be better if there was an error though. If you define `const unsound = somefn<{prop1:{val1:2}, prop2:{val1:2}}>()`, then `unsound.val1 !== undefined ? unsound.val1 : null` yields type `2 | null`, which is clearly incorrect.